# Split a big UIImage for Texture Use

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to split a big Image ( about 10000px Height ) in a number of smaller Images to use them as Textures for a OpenGL, below is the way I'm doing it right now, anybody got any ideas to do it faster, because it is taking quite long.

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray alloc] initWith 
for (int i = 0; i<numberOfImages; i++){

    int t = i*origHeight;
    CGRect fromRect = CGRectMake(0, t, origWidth, origHeight); // or whatever rectangle

    CGImageRef drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImage.CGImage, fromRect);

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage],1.0)];

    [images addObject:newImage];

    CGImageRelease(drawImage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-split them before ie using the `convert` command with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which you can get with [brew](https://brew.sh/)

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15771